# How to calculate this answer?

Tags: c

Can you please tell me why in below code answer is 1610612736?
How to calculate this answer?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
       float h=4.1;
       printf("\n%d\n",h);
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Turn your warning level up. The compiler should be telling you the problem.

Comment: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
      'float' [-Wformat]

Answer (score 3):

Do this instead:

```
printf("\n %f", h);
```

You need to use the right specifier... you were using `%d` which is for integers.

Comment: I know that I use of %f, but why for the %d answer is 1610612736?